# How to restore the objects constructed from other activity after the OS kill/restore this activity

Tags: android-activity, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

Having two modules, `activity 1` from `module 1` will set up some objects as the running context based on the user action. And it will launch the `activity 2` from the `module 2`. And the `activity 2` from `module 1` will be using the updated object as running context for its processing.

The question is when `OS kills the process and restores` (under resource constraints, i.e. received a phone call which hides the app - os kills the process - after phone call os restores the app),  the OS will restores the `last activity` on the top but the running context setup by the previous activity is gone, how to restore the `running context`.

example:

```
interface Handler {
    fun func_1(data: Data)
    fun func_2 (data: Data)

}

class Processor (val hanlder: Handler, var which: Int) {

    fun doProcess(data: Data) {
        when (which) {
            1 -> {
                hanlder.func_1(data)
            }
            2-> {
                hanlder.func_2(data)
            }
        }
    }

}


//using global (good or bad???) to avoid passing obj crossing activities
object Running_context {
    lateinit var _processor: Processor
    fun setProcessor(processor: Processor) {
        this._processor = processor
    }

    fun getProcessor() :Processor {
        return this._processor
    }

}
```

in `module 1`, the `activity_1` will setup the running context based on user's action like:

```
fun launch_activity_2 (which: Int) {
    var processor = Processor (object: Handler {
        override fun func_1(data: String) {
            // do something based on some data get from use in this activity
            // e.g: if (checkBox_a.isChecked) {do something...}
        }
        override fun func_2 (data: String) {
            // do other things...
        }
    }, which)

    // set up running context
    Running_context.setProcessor(processor)

    // launching the activity_2 from module_2
    // ...
}
```

and in the launched `activity 2` (in module 2) will do the process based on the setup by `activity 1`:

```
fun doProcess(data: String) {
    Running_context.getProcessor().doProcess(data)
}
```

When referring a global instance of `object Running_context` it avoids to pass the `object/function point` across the activities.

But still when OS is under constraints it may kill the process then restore it, and at the restore flow the last activity is `activity 2` from `module 2` and the global instance does not have the correct running context of last time.

1. What is the best way to pass the object/function point to another activity and make them be restored when os kills/restores that activity?
2. Another question, what if the activity 2 is from a 3rd party lib and does not have access to the `global object Running_context`, so that the running context has to be passed into the new instance of the `activity 2'?`  (the `interface Handler` and `class Processor` are defined in `module 2` which `module 1` is depending on)

Comment: It's ok to use Globals as long as you can properly Restore them. But if you don't know how to do that, then just use regular intent extras / argument bundles.

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce, for those dynamically create instance Processor object how to put them in bundle since the functions could be generated at activity_1's runtime. kinda of lost. , the sample is simplified, the Processor has some map with some function point, and some internal class which is only defined in the module 1, not visible directly in module 2 (module 1 depending on module 2)

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to realize,  even storing data in a global singleton does not help when an app is killed and the restored.  I think the best thing you can do is find a good place in the lifecycle of each activity (onPause and onResume are good) to serialize/de-derialize  and save/restore the data to persistent storage.

Take a look at the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage) on this subject.  If you don't have a huge complicated object,  I like to use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences).

> Shared preferences If you don't need to store a lot of data and it
>   doesn't require structure, you should use SharedPreferences. The
>   SharedPreferences APIs allow you to read and write persistent
>   key-value pairs of primitive data types: booleans, floats, ints,
>   longs, and strings.
>
> The key-value pairs are written to XML files that persist across user
>   sessions, even if your app is killed. You can manually specify a name
>   for the file or use per-activity files to save your data.
>
> The API name "shared preferences" is a bit misleading because the API
>   is not strictly for saving "user preferences," such as what ringtone a
>   user has chosen. You can use SharedPreferences to save any kind of
>   simple data, such as the user's high score. However, if you do want to
>   save user preferences for your app, then you should read how to create
>   a settings UI, which uses the AndroidX Preference Library to build a
>   settings screen and automatically persist the user's settings.

Comment: thanks @nPn! As @EpicPandaForce suggested the right direction is to using just use regular intent extras / argument bundles.  The problem is now that there are a few functions dynamically constructed at runtime (some data injected in the function bock), and to make them in a parceble.  The Shared preferences is not a option here.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question,  and make it clear what you need to pass/share,  for example it's not clear what you mean by "functions dynamically constructed at runtime".  I think the comment about it being OK to use globals , but needing to properly restore them is correct.  One way to properly restore them is to have them be a cached object based on some persisted data,  so you need some mechanism to serialize and de-serialize the object, and you need to know when the cached object is not valid, ie when the app is restored from being killed.

Comment: If you don't need the performance of the globals solution, you can just stick to persisted data,  since ultimately you need to to that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestion from @EpicPandaForce and @nPn, using bundle to pass the context.

here is the idea,  hope someone have a better way, thx!

In `module 2`, define a base processor class for derived from:

```
open class BaseProcessor() : Parcelable {

    open fun doProcess(data: Data){}

    // parceable stuff below
    /......
}
```

In `module 1` create a class with the handler functions

```
class TheHandler() {
   func_1 (data: Data) {
   }

   func_2 (data: Data) {
   }
}
```

making the `Processor` derived from BaseProcessor (could have a few primitive data to be serialized so it is small) and override the `doProcess(data: Data)`,
it will instantiate a `TheHandler` class at runtime when the `doProcess(data: Data)` is called, and calling the proper function based on the context value (i.e. the `var which: Int`)

```
class Processor (var which: Int) : BaseProcessor {

    override fun doProcess(data: Data) {
        val handler = TheHandler()
        when (which) {
            1 -> {
                handler.func_1(data)
            }
            2-> {
                hanlder.func_2(data)
            }
        }
    }

    // parcelable stuff
    // ... ...
    override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
            out.writeInt(this.which)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Processor> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Processor> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Processor {
                return Processor(parcel)
            }

            override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Processor?> {
                return arrayOfNulls(size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when launch the `activity 2`, it construct the `Processor` with context data and put in the bundle for the new `activity 2`

```
fun launch_activity_2 (which: Int) {
    var processor = Processor (which)

    // put processor in the bundle
    args.putParcelable(KEY_PROCESSOR_CONFIG, processor)

    // launching the activity_2 from module_2 with the bundle passed in 
    // ...
}
```

In module 2's activity 2, it expects to get a BaseProcessor out of the bundle and call the function `doProces()`
and the  `processor` (which is instance of `Processor`)  will have the context info and choose the proper function provided through the `TheHandler` class from the `module 1`'s `activity 1`.

```
fun doProcess(data: String) {
    //somethinglike:

    val processor: BaseProcessor? = arguments?.getParcelable(KEY_PROCESSOR_CONFIG)
    processor?.doProcess(data)
}
```